# Сумма цифр из числа введенного пользователем (PHP)

Tags: php

Подскажите, как сложить сумму чисел введенного пользователем? К примеру 534 должно быть 12

Comment: В чем ваша проблема состоит с подсчетом суммы цифр?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow на русском! Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно так:

```
echo array_sum(str_split('534'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumInt($var) {
    $var = strval($var);
    $sum = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($var); $i++) {
        $sum += (int)$var[$i];
    }

    return $sum;
}

$sum = sumInt(534);
```